# Evaluating the limit of the sequence: $\frac{ 1^a + 2^a +..... n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[n^2a + n(n+1)/2]}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, closed-form

My friend gave me this question to solve a few days ago and after I got no way to solve this, I thought I should seek some help.

I had to evaluate the limit of the following when $n$ tends to infinite.

$$ \frac{ 1^a + 2^a +..... n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[n^2a + n(n+1)/2]}$$

I tried to convert this limit into a definite integral but I couldn't get the expression solely in the  terms of $(r/n)$

Any help on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Note: I know to solve limit of certain  series by turning it into an integral from the  following form:
$$\sum\frac{f(r/n)}{n}$$
It turns into an integral of $f(r/n)$.

Comment: By 'friend' you meant 'lecturer'?)

Comment: @alex friend refers to a school friend. Anyways, I forgot to write the complete question. I had to find 'a' and the value of the limit was given to be some 'x' which i do not remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given expression can be written as 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{a-1}}&\frac{1}{\left(a+\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^a \\
&= \frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^1 x^a dx \\
&= \frac{2}{1+2a}\frac{1}{a+1} \\
&= \frac{2}{(a+1)(2a+1)}
\end{align*}

Comment: The answer obtained by both methods is same might mean it is correct. Didn't knew that I could take n out of the integral.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may use that, for a fixed real number $a>0$, as $n \to \infty$ we have
$$
1^a + 2^a +..... n^a \sim \frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1} \tag1
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{ 1^a + 2^a +..... n^a}{(n+1)^{a-1}[n^2a + n(n+1)/2]}&\sim\frac{\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}}{n^2\cdot (n+1)^{a-1}\left(a + \frac12+\frac1{2n}\right)}
\\\\&\sim \frac{\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}}{n^2\cdot n^{a-1}\left(a +  \frac12\right)}
\\\\&\sim \frac{1}{(a+1)\left(a +  \frac12\right)} \tag2
\end{align}
$$ which is the desired limit.

Comment: I think the coefficent of  $n^2$ in the denominator should be $a+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Appreciate your solution olivier. Can't this be solved by integration because the identity you used was unknown to me.

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal.  Equation $(1)$ comes from the fact that $1^a + 2^a +..... n^a =H_n^{(-a)}$ where the rhs is the generalized harmonic number and the first term of its asymptotics is what Olivier Oloa wrote.